# Can you have multiple events per component reference?

Tags: angular

I have a basic question that I am struggling to find answers to online, it it alright to have two events or more per component reference i.e.:

```
<app-inputs (event)="getDataFromChild($event)",
(eventTwo)="getDataFromChildTwo($eventTwo)"></app-inputs>
```

Comment: You can have multiple events as long as the events are different.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction to the number of `events` (output events w.r.t angular) registered against a `component`.
Only thing is all those events should be different.

```
<app-inputs 
(event)="getDataFromChild($event)"
(eventTwo)="getDataFromChildTwo($event)"
(event_N)="getDataFromChild_N($event)"></app-inputs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add events as much as you can until they are different.
Same behaviour you can see in many libraries component like [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng).

Different means to say here every event can refer to different event like some is for `mouseevent` for `keyup` `keydown` etc.